# How can I pass a function's name to a function, and then call it?

Tags: python

1. How can I pass a functions name to a function and then call it?
   Is it possible to do this without using `getattribute`?
2. How can I pass a class name to a function and then instantiate the class?
   I know I just could pass the instance of the class directly to the function but it is important that the class gets instantiated **after** calling the function.

Comment: What's the reason for not using getattr? Seem the obvious solution.

Comment: well... I can't be sure that the class is a new-style-class :-/

Comment: You should be passing the class, not the class name. Create the instance by calling the class exactly the same way as you would call the function in SilentGhost's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def outer(f):          # any name: function, class, any callable
    return f()         # class will be instantiated within the scope of the function
```

Comment: `name` is usually a `string`. And `string` is not callable.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace = globals()
result = namespace[func_name]()
instance = namespace[class_name](*some_args)
```

You can use your own dictionary (namespace) instead of `globals`.

It is unclear why do you need artificial constrains such as not passing directly function/class objects, not using `getattr()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of options your planning to use, you could set up a dictionary with string keys and values of the functions/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the function and the class directly?

```
class A(object):
    pass
def f():
    pass
def g(func, cls):
    func()
    x = cls()
g(f, A)
```